# t-sql secondary pivot on pivoted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How would I pivot this table again to account for the difference in names?

What I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp
(
    badge  nvarchar(4)
   ,name   nvarchar(31)
   ,Job    nvarchar(4)
   ,KDA    float
   ,Match  int
)

INSERT INTO Temp
VALUES ('T996', 'Darrien', 'AP', 1.0, 20),
       ('T996', 'Mark', 'ADC', 2.8, 16),
       ('T996', 'Kevin', 'TOP', 5.0, 120)

SELECT badge, [AP_KDA], [AP_Match], [ADC_KDA], [ADC_Match], [TOP_KDA], [TOP_Match], [Person]
FROM (
    SELECT badge, Col, Val
    FROM (
          SELECT badge, Job + '_KDA' AS Col, CAST(KDA AS nvarchar(31)) AS Val
          FROM Temp
          UNION ALL
          SELECT badge, Job + '_Match' AS Col, CAST(Match AS nvarchar(31)) AS Val  
          FROM Temp
          UNION ALL
          SELECT badge, 'Person' AS Col, name AS Val
          FROM Temp
    ) AS t
) AS tt
PIVOT (MIN(Val) FOR Col IN ([AP_KDA], [AP_Match], [ADC_KDA], [ADC_Match], [TOP_KDA], [TOP_Match], [Person])
) AS pvt
```

Which outputs:

```
   badge AP_KDA AP_Match ADC_KDA ADC_Match  TOP_KDA TOP_Match Person
1  T996  1      20       2.8     16         5       120       Darrien
```

I would like it to be formatted as:

```
   badge AP_KDA AP_Match ADC_KDA ADC_Match  TOP_KDA TOP_Match Person1 Person2 Person3
1  T996  1      20       2.8     16         5       120       Darrien Mark  Kevin
```

I believe I'm close but the final Pivot is throwing me off.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create columns, meaning lets say you had a `person4`, you just cannot do it using `PIVOT` alone. You have to use `For xml` to transpose your data or another option is to use cursors, but I personally prefer `For Xml`. See this post for [for xml](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/)

Comment: Wound up using this method `For XML` instead to make the query more dynamic. Thanks, that link helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function*, `MAX` with `CASE WHEN` to make pivot.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp
(
    badge  nvarchar(4),
    name   nvarchar(31),
    Job   nvarchar(4),
    KDA   float,
    Match  int
 )

 INSERT INTO Temp VALUES
 ( 'T996'  ,  'Darrien'  , 'AP'  , 1.0,   20),
 ('T996'   ,  'Mark'  , 'ADC'  , 2.8   ,   16),
 ( 'T996'  ,  'Kevin'  , 'TOP' ,  5.0   ,   120)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT badge,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'AP' THEN KDA END)    AP_KDA,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'AP' THEN Match END)  AP_Match,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'ADC' THEN KDA END)   ADC_KDA,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'ADC' THEN Match END) ADC_Match,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'TOP' THEN KDA END)   TOP_KDA,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'TOP' THEN Match END) TOP_Match,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'AP' THEN  name END)  Person1 ,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'ADC' THEN name END)  Person2 ,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'TOP' THEN name END)  Person3
FROM TEMP
GROUP BY  badge
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65295/7/0)**:

```
| badge | AP_KDA | AP_Match | ADC_KDA | ADC_Match | TOP_KDA | TOP_Match | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 |
|-------|--------|----------|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  T996 |      1 |       20 |     2.8 |        16 |       5 |       120 | Darrien |    Mark |   Kevin |
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty easy and straightforward doing it this way. Wound up using `For XML` instead since it would make the query more dynamic. But tbf this does exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```
  SELECT badge, [AP_KDA], [AP_Match], [ADC_KDA], [ADC_Match], [TOP_KDA], [TOP_Match], 
  [Person1],[Person2],[Person3]
 FROM (
          SELECT badge, Col, Val
         FROM (
               SELECT badge, Job + '_KDA' AS Col, CAST(KDA AS nvarchar(31)) AS Val
               FROM Temp
               UNION ALL
               SELECT badge, Job + '_Match' AS Col, CAST(Match AS nvarchar(31)) AS 
                Val  
              FROM Temp
              UNION ALL
              SELECT badge, 'Person'+ CAST ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY badge 
              ORDER BY name DESC)) AS VARCHAR) AS Col, CAST(name AS VARCHAR) AS Val
               FROM Temp
           ) AS t
          ) AS tt
        PIVOT (MIN(Val) FOR Col IN ([AP_KDA], [AP_Match], [ADC_KDA], [ADC_Match], 
        [TOP_KDA], [TOP_Match], [Person1],[Person2],[Person3])
        ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty much what I was looking for previously. I wound up going with `For XML` instead since it would make the code more dynamic and flexible.